# lua encryption doesn't wait for functions to complete

Tags: encryption, lua, roblox

This a ROBLOX lua script, lua 5.1 with features that have been modified, removed, or added,  Anyone with lua 5.1 knowledge, will help greatly.

My issue is that when I try to obfuscate this script:

```
_G.findchild = function (instance, name)
for _, child in pairs(instance:GetChildren()) do
    if child.Name == name then
        return true
    elseif _==#instance:GetChildren() then
        return false
    end
end
end
print(_G.findchild(game,"Workspace"))
```

It doesn't wait for the function to complete in the print, and it just prints nothing (nil),  not false or true

Here is the encryption script (note I commented out the io.write lines, roblox removed this library)

https://pastebin.com/TcHTBf3C

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to add, the script also doesn't support long scripts.

Comment: Did you mean to use `ipairs` instead of `pairs`? The order, in which keys are returned, can vary when using the latter.  Also, instead of using the `elseif`, it would seem cleaner to either use `else`, or add `return false` after the `for … end`. OT: What's the intend behind writing `_G.findchild = function (…)` instead of `function findchild (…)`?

Comment: @tarleb I am using ipairs because I see no noticeable difference between the two. I use elseif because I have to find out of the index of the loop is at the end. I use a global variable because I have to use it across multiple scripts.

Comment: I asked about `ipairs` and `pairs` because they are *very* different, especially in the order in which they return key-value pairs. This was meant as an encouragement to read up on them.